# Getting errors when trying to implement ReplayKit

Tags: ios, swift3, replaykit

I am using SpriteKit to build a game. I an trying to implement ReplayKit but I am getting a few errors. This is the code I am using.

```
    func startRecording() {
    let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

    recorder.startRecording(withMicrophoneEnabled: true) { [unowned self] (error) in
        if let unwrappedError = error {
            print(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)
        } else {

        }
    }
}

func stopRecording() {
    let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

    recorder.stopRecording { [unowned self] (preview, error) in

        if let unwrappedPreview = preview {
            unwrappedPreview.previewControllerDelegate = self
            //Error in the line below
            self.present(unwrappedPreview, animated: true)
        }
    }
}


 func previewControllerDidFinish(_ previewController: RPPreviewViewController) {
   //Error in the line below
    dismiss(animated: true)
 }
```

The first error is "Value of type GameScene has no member present" and the second error is "Use of unresolved identifier dismiss"

What am I doing wrong, I have imported ReplayKit and have added the RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate to my GameScene class.

Comment: Is your GameScene an instance of SKScene?

Answer (score 0):

Well, both, the `present` and `dismiss` functions are instance methods of UIViewController. Your GameScene class obviously **does not inherit from UIViewController** which is why those functions aren't available to its instances. You're basically trying to call something, that doesn't exist.

Try moving your code to an instance of [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller).